# Wordpress 3.8 403 when trying to create a new menu

Tags: wordpress

I have a (almost simple) wordpress installation, upgraded to 3.8 in the last days.
Now I have to create a new menu and get a 403:
"You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/nav-menus.php on this server."

It's strange, I can access the default main menu and edit and change it with this file, but "/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=0" does not work.
Googled and found some who have the same problem but no solution.

Ah, nav-menus.php is 644 in a 755 folder.

I hope someone can help me...

Comment: found workaround: there is definitely something broken with it's .htaccess. renamed it, was able to create the new menu and back renamend it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem and asked my host to look at the mod_sec on the server.  Something happened and it triggered on the firewall and was giving me random 403 errors throughout my Wordpress admin.  If you are unable to fix it by resetting your htaccess, permissions etc. I would talk to your host and mention "mod_sec"